# MySQL - Criar um alias concatenando vários campos

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-select, concatenação-de-string

É possível criar um alias concatenando outros campos? Ex:

```sql
SELECT u.nome, u.sobrenome AS nome_completo
FROM usuarios u
```

No exemplo, quero concatenar **u.nome** e **u.sobrenome** e armazenar no campo **nome_completo**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.nome,' ', u.sobrenome) nome_completo
FROM usuarios u
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT u.nome + ' ' + u.sobrenome AS nome_completo FROM usuarios u
```

ou

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.nome + " " + u.sobrenome) AS nome_completo FROM
usuarios u;
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra forma de fazer isso seria esta:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", u.nome, u.sobrenome) AS nome_completo FROM usuarios u;
```

A diferença em relação ao CONCAT é que o separado é definido no primeiro parâmetro.